# Elasticsearch how to count specific values from multiple fields across all documents in index?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have WRC standings into my ES index. Each driver has its own document.
[image]

Mapping for this index:

```
`{
  "properties" : {
    "Argentina pts" : {
      "type" : "long"
    },
    "Argentina result" : {
      "type" : "long"
    },
    "Chile pts" : {
      "type" : "long"
    },
    "Chile result" : {
      "type" : "long"
    },
    "Driver" : {
      "type" : "keyword"
    }
    "Nationality" : {
      "type" : "keyword"
    }
    "Team" : {
      "type" : "keyword"
    },
    "Total" : {
      "type" : "long"
    },
    "Position" : {
      "type" : "long"
    }`
```

Example document:

```
"_source" : {
      "Argentina pts" : 30,
      "Argentina result" : 1,
      "Chile pts" : 30,
      "Chile result" : 1,
      "Driver" : "O. TANAK",
      "Nationality" : "Estonia",
      "Team" : "Toyota",
      "Total" : 263,
      "Position" : 1,

    }
```

**Question**

How to count drivers wins depending on `result` fields? I tried different queries and/or aggregations but the closest result I got are drivers with at least one win in season ( I used `multi_match` for this). I didn't find the answer on Stack or Elastic documentation. I don't know how to search documents "vertically" through multiple fields and make aggregations on selected fields.

**EDIT**

I want to count for every driver only `result` fields which are equal 1. So for example if driver won in Monaco (`Monaco result`=1) the query/script will increase his win counter.

**Example response**

```
{
"Driver" : "a",
"Win count": 3
},
{
"Driver" : "b",
"Win count": 2
},
{
"Driver" : "c",
"Win count": 1
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of what do you want? just to be clear.

Comment: @nimeresam added an example

Comment: What classifies as a win? just the `position` field equal to 1? or do you need to have `Chile result`=1 if `Nationality`='Chile'?

Comment: @RonSerruya sorry I should mention it. Your meaning is right. Win is for example `Chile result` = 1 and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

So given the definition of a "win" being that the `<Driver nationality> result` == 1, you can use this query

```json
{
  "query": {
    "script": {
      "script": "def nat = doc['Nationality'].value; return doc[nat + ' result'].value == 1"
    }
  }
}
```